# trim function is not working in model file of codeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I just want to trim file name before store into Database but it showing actual file name like "abc def.jpg", please see my code and suggest me the solution.

```
<?php
class service_model extends CI_Model{
    public function set_service()
{
    $data = array(
        'serviceName' => $this->input->post('serviceName'),
        'servicePhoto' => trim($_FILES["servicePhoto"]['name']),
        'dateCreated' => $this->input->post('dateCreated')
    );
    return $this->db->insert('services', $data);
}
}
```

Comment: What goes wrong?

Comment: @Grumpy trim($_FILES["servicePhoto"]['name']) it giving actual file name without trim like "abc def.jpg"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

trim() as in you code just remove space at beginning and end

```
    trim($_FILES["servicePhoto"]['name'])
```

you want remove also space between words you need  replace

```
   str_replace(' ', '', $_FILES["servicePhoto"]['name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

another codeigniter helper you can use is `url_title()` function.

something like this will work for you.

```
url_title(trim($_FILES["servicePhoto"]['name']));
```

it replaces space with dash `-`.

Comment: $url_title = url_title($title, 'underscore'); url_title() is working well with underscore. @Ali Qorbani thank you

Comment: yw. 
it depends on your config setting.